# Не получается использовать две разные формы от разных моделей на одной странице. Django 2

Tags: django

Вызываю форму TarifStartForm. Форма открывается верно, но после нажатия кнопки submit данные сохраняются в модель TarifIndividual.

views.py

```
class TarifyView(CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = TarifIndividual
    template_name = 'tarify.html'
    form_class = TarifIndividualForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tarify')
    success_msg = 'Сообщение отправлено'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['startform'] = TarifStartForm
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class TarifStartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TarifStart
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class TarifIndividualForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TarifIndividual
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

tarify.html

```
<!-- Всплывашка заказать Start-->
<div class="modal fade" id="order" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticOrder" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header my_color">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticOrder">Заказать Start</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close cross_color" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="add_form_order" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{startform}}
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>-->
        <button form="add_form_order" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить заявку</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Всплывашка заказать Start END-->      

<!-- Всплывашка заказать Individual-->
<div class="modal fade" id="individual" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticindividual" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header my_color">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticindividual">Заказать Individual</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close cross_color" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="add_form_individual" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>-->
        <button form="add_form_individual" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить заявку</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Всплывашка заказать Individual END-->
```

Comment: а что конкретно не получается ?

Comment: Забыл написать) Вызываю форму TarifStartForm. Форма открывается верно, но после нажатия кнопки submit данные сохраняются в модель TarifIndividual.

Comment: в вашей views вижу только `model = TarifIndividual`

Comment: а как должно быть? Можно две модели указать?

Answer (score 0):

так как ты хочешь, что бы обработка обоих форм у тебя была в одном месте, то для начала
я бы добавил в каждую из форм поле `prefix`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms), что бы когда поступали данные к тебе ты точно мог идентифицировать из какой формы они пришли (так как могут быть пересекающиеся поля) и при частичном заполнении(только пересекающихся полей) может быть непонятно какая именно форма заполнялась.

дальше ты используешь CreateView, но все подобные View(наследники `FormView`) в django заточены для работы именно с одной формой. Если у тебя есть несколько форм, то тебе нужно делать обработку самостоятельно, например переопределив метод post

```
class TarifyView(CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # тут по наличию тех или иных полей нужно определить какая именно форма обрабатывалась, 
        # это можно сделать добавив какое-то скрытое поле в каждую из форм или используя уникальное поле 
        # и тут проверять наличие этого поля в request.POST
        is_start_form = request.POST.get('start-input-unique', None) is not None
        if is_start_form:
            form = TarifStartForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = TarifIndividualForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Либо можно создать несколько view. `View` где рендерится страница с формами, потом на каждую из форм создал свою `CreateView`, в которой бы обрабатывал свою форму. Если там много общей логики предполагается, то в итоге одна из View наследовалась бы от другой, что бы не переписывать логику.

Comment: view не имеет object  - такая ошибка выходит, если я использую этот код.

Comment: если я делаю несколько view то post не отправляется, ошибку не пишет, но POST  идет с кодом 200, а не 302

Comment: Я в коде указал, только необходимые изменения. Остальные вещи, такие как `model`, `template_name`,  `form_class` тоже необходимо оставить